# Facebook, App Links on Android: not getting the schema (Uri for the App Link's Android URL) on the field 'data' of the Intent

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

We are developing Facebook AppLinks for Android.

We followed all the directives from Facebook Developer page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

1. In our Web page (the target url) we define the metas:

> ```
>   <meta property="al:android:url" content="mySchema://?id=3643020" />
>   <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="myAppName" />
>   <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.my.package" />
>   <meta property="al:android:class" content="com.my.package.screens.BrowseableActivity"/>
> ```

inside the  tag.

For the Schema, we also tried with this one:

```
  <meta property="al:android:url" content="mySchema://id=3643020" />

    (without the ? character)
```

2. In our Android App, in the Manifest for the BrowseableActivity we define:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".screens.BrowseableActivity" 
       android:theme="@style/Theme.myAppName.myTheme" >    
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.my.package.screens.BrowseableActivity" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter> 
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="mySchema"/>
       </intent-filter>      
   </activity>
   ```

When we test:

1. We share from our App a link to Facebook, where the "link" property is the 'target url' that has the metas.
   That is ok.
2. Inside the Facebook Android App (version 18.0.0.24.14) we see the post shared in the previous step.
3. We click on the post, and our App is open!
   Everything is ok until here.

OUR PROBLEM:

According to Facebook documentation in the Intent that opens our "BrowseableActivity", the 'data' field 
should have the following information:

```
data: "mySchema://id=3643020?target_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ourtargeturl.com%2Fdirectory"

this is: the Schema (Uri or Android Url) and the Target_url
```

But for us, we only got this:

```
data: "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ourtargeturl.com%2Fdirectory"

We only got the target_url.
```

In this page of Facebook ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android ) they said that 
if you don't receive 'the Schema' if because you don't define the meta "al:android:url" in the 
target_url. But, we define it.

Also, in the others fields of the Intent, (the extras x example) we don't see 'the Schema' information.

And that info is what we need, and we don't know what else to try.

Thanks,

Comment: Where did you define the id in `mySchema://?id=3643020`?

Comment: The id is a product id that is the same for our website and app. That uri is defined server side on our website and printed out in meta tags in the html of the product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify the class name. If you specify the class name, it will use the package name/class name combination to create an intent with a componentName that directly addresses your app/activity. What goes in the "data" field is actually undefined at that point.

If you skip specifying the al:android:class property, then it will use your custom url.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Removed the class name meta and was able to get the data.